# Troubleshooting UWSGI NGINX WEB2PY. Can access only one app

Tags: nginx, web2py, uwsgi

Good day.
I have configured NGINX as a reverse proxy server that speaks with UWSGI that in turn should call/run *web2py* applications. It is several applications in *web2py/applications/...* but I'm able to get response only from the one of them.
I think the problem is *mount* or *chdir* options within *.ini* file monitored by UWSGI.

```
[uwsgi]    
socket = 127.0.0.1:9002   
chdir = /var/www/web2py/  
mount = /=wsgihandler:application
...
```

Can any one suggest proper config that all the applications will be accessible via web?

Answer (score 0):

[This script](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/R-2.14.6/scripts/setup-web2py-nginx-uwsgi-ubuntu.sh) includes an Nginx+uWSGI configuration that should work for web2py.